# Tkinter Large Text Dialogue (save string on button click)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a large text-entry popup as part of a gui.  The idea is to get paragraph-long user-input.  The problem is that the method `get_big_text()` returns before the button is pushed.  How can I have a separate window pop-up like this, and be able to save the user's text to a variable in my control program?  Everything else in my program has been working out, until I tried to implement this.  I am new to gui programming.  I get the feeling that there is something fundamentally different about waiting for user input here, but I can't wrap my head around it in the functional context.

My goal is to have the line `print(foo.get_big_text())` print the user's text, but of course it prints `None` because the `get_big_text()` method finishes.

I have left out the details of the rest of the gui, and wrote an `__init__()` that probably doesn't need to be there, but this is the basics of how my gui is coming along.  The `Toplevel` widget is the only widget in my gui that is not somehow connected to `root`.

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        tframe = Frame(root)
        tframe.pack(side='top')
        bframe = Frame(root)
        bframe.pack(side='bottom')
        self.txt = Text(tframe)
        self.txt.insert('0.0', 'Totally foobar')
        self.txt.pack()
        self.btn = Button(bframe, text='OK')
        self.btn.pack()


    def get_big_text(self, title='', text=''):
        popup = Toplevel(height=160, width=180)
        popup.title(title)
        txtframe = Frame(popup)
        txtframe.pack()
        big_text = Text(txtframe)
        big_text.insert('0.0',text)
        big_text.pack()
        btnframe = Frame(popup)
        btnframe.pack()
        grab_text = Button(btnframe)
        grab_text.config(text="Done", command=lambda: big_text.get('0.0', 'end'))
        grab_text.pack()

root=Tk()
root.title('Example')
foo = Gui(root)
print(foo.get_big_text())
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some suggestions from @xndrme, and some hard thinking, I realized the solution is quite simple.  It's just that I'm not used to programing in this functional style.  Really fun to discover this, though.

I wanted the `get_big_text()` method to return the text so that I could pass it somewhere else and "do something" with it when the text comes.  The solution was to pass an anonymous function to the method and "tell it" what should be done with it when it does come.

Note the new `callback` parameter in `get_big_text()`

```
from tkinter import *

class Gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        tframe = Frame(root)
        tframe.pack(side='top')
        bframe = Frame(root)
        bframe.pack(side='bottom')
        self.txt = Text(tframe)
        self.txt.insert('0.0', 'Totally foobar')
        self.txt.pack()
        self.btn = Button(bframe, text='OK')
        self.btn.pack()


    def get_big_text(self, callback, title='', text=''):
        popup = Toplevel(height=160, width=180)
        popup.title(title)
        txtframe = Frame(popup)
        txtframe.pack()
        big_text = Text(txtframe)
        big_text.insert('0.0',text)
        big_text.pack()
        btnframe = Frame(popup)
        btnframe.pack()
        grab_text = Button(btnframe)
        grab_text.config(text="Done", command=lambda:callback(big_text.get('0.0', 'end')))
        grab_text.pack()

root=Tk()
root.title('Example')
foo = Gui(root)
foo.get_big_text(lambda x:print(x))
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the text to one function in your class and then do whatever you want with it (like printing):

```
from Tkinter import *

class Gui:

    def __init__(self, root):
        tframe = Frame(root)
        tframe.pack(side='top')
        bframe = Frame(root)
        bframe.pack(side='bottom')
        self.txt = Text(tframe)
        self.txt.insert('0.0', 'Totally foobar')
        self.txt.pack()
        self.btn = Button(bframe, text='OK')
        self.btn.pack()

    def f(self, text):
        print(text)        

    def get_big_text(self, title='', text=''):
        popup = Toplevel(height=160, width=180)
        popup.title(title)
        txtframe = Frame(popup)
        txtframe.pack()
        big_text = Text(txtframe)
        big_text.insert('0.0',text)
        big_text.pack()
        btnframe = Frame(popup)
        btnframe.pack()
        grab_text = Button(btnframe)
        grab_text.config(text="Done", command=lambda: self.f(big_text.get('0.0', 'end')))
        grab_text.pack()

root=Tk()
root.title('Example')
foo = Gui(root)
foo.get_big_text()
root.mainloop()
```

If you want to print the text **after** the gui finished you can do this modifications:

1. On `Gui.f`:

   ```
       def f(self, text):
           self.text = text
   ```
2. At the end of your code:

   ```
   root.mainloop()
   print(foo.text)
   ```

Comment: The only problem with that idea is that I don't want the gui to have anything to say about "what" I'm going to do with it.  I just want a way to tell the gui to get text from the user, then return it.

Comment: And thats exactly what you need to do on the `f` function as I said, you store the text and then return it to the user

Comment: You should keep in mind that gui programming is event-based so you will never be able to get the text before you start the main event loop (currently on line `root.mainloop()`) so you should _move_ your code to the function `Gui.f` or call another function from within `f`, Just check that on your code `foo.get_big_text()` is called **before** the event loop.

Comment: check the modifications on my answer, maybe that could help you, hope it helps :)

Comment: Actually, I ran into the same fundamental problem, but I figured it out because of this conversation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The general flow for a dialog is to create the window, then call `wait_window` to wait until the window has been dismissed by the user. Your function can then return whatever you want.

There's a bit of a chicken-and-egg thing going on, in that you need to get the value from the dialog *before* the dialog is destroyed since the text widget will be destroyed when the toplevel is destroyed. You do this by explicitly managing the destruction of the window (read: get the value before actually destroying the window).

Here's a working example, trying to preserve as much as code as possible but without using a global import:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class CustomDialog(object):
    def __init__(self, parent, title="Enter a paragraph", default_text=""):
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = title
        self.default = default_text

    def show(self):
        self.popup = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.popup.title(self.title)
        txtframe = tk.Frame(self.popup)
        txtframe.pack()
        self.big_text = tk.Text(txtframe)
        self.big_text.insert('1.0',self.default)
        self.big_text.pack()
        btnframe = tk.Frame(self.popup)
        btnframe.pack()
        grab_text = tk.Button(btnframe)
        grab_text.config(text="Done", command=self.done)
        grab_text.pack()

        # make sure our "done" method gets called even if the
        # user destroys the window
        self.popup.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.done)

        # wait for the window to be destroyed
        root.wait_window(self.popup)
        return self.data

    def done(self, *args):
        # get the data from the window, then destroy
        # the window and return to the caller
        self.data = self.big_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        self.popup.destroy()

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        b = tk.Button(self, text="Get Input", command=self.go)
        b.pack()

    def go(self):
        dialog = CustomDialog(self, default_text="totally foobar")
        result = dialog.show()
        print "result:", result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Another option that you have is to pass a callback to your dialog, and tie that callback to the "done" button. That way, whenever the user clicks the button, you execute the callback to do whatever you want with the data before destroying the window.

That is how you implement a non-modal dialog, since you don't necessarily have to destroy the window. Font dialogs are a good example of this, where you might want to keep the dialog open for quite a while, and affect whatever is currently selected.

The effbot site has a decent writeup on dialogs. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm